# конструктор для класса беззнаковых int на 64 бит

Tags: c++, классы, int, unsigned

Задача написать класс для беззнаковых интов на 64 бита.
Как проверить в конструкторе, что передано не минусовое значение, ведь цифры перекручиваются в положительном диапазоне?

Если принимать знаковые переменные для инициализации, то не хватает разрядов, если передавать большое (предельное) беззнаковое значение.

Никак не дотумкаю как проверять, HELP, пожалуйста.

```cpp
Long::Long(uint64_t first, uint64_t second)
{   
    if (first < 0 or second < 0)
    {
        cout << "Что-то пошло не так, невозможно создать объект.\nПрограмма завершена аварийно.\n" << endl;    
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    else
    {
        Number_1 = first; Number_2 = second;
        cout << "Создан объект класса Long. Число 1 = " << Number_1 << ". Число 2 = " << Number_2 << ".\n" << endl;    
    }
}
```

```cpp
TEST-CASES

Long C(0, -1);
0 18446744073709551615

Long D(18000000000000000000, 18446744073709551615);
Создан объект класса Long. Число 1 = 0. Число 2 = 18446744073709551615.

18000000000000000000 18446744073709551615
Создан объект класса Long. Число 1 = 18000000000000000000. Число 2 = 18446744073709551615.

===============================================================================
test cases: 1 | 1 passed
```

Comment: код и тесты загружены

Comment: uint64_t не может быть меньше 0, т.к. это ТОЛЬКО положительное число

Comment: А почему в классе хранится два числа?

Comment: Понятно, что беззнаковый не может быть меньше 0, но если передали минусовое число в конструктор - как это отловить? Вот -1 передали и это уже ошибка, т.к. в итоге число перекручивается и выдается максимальное значение. А программа должна завершать работу при передаче -1.

Comment: Я не понял. Беззнаковый int 64 бита это собственно int64_t. Зачем вы его пытаетесь в класс обернуть?

Comment: Проверяйте не в конструкторе или передавайте бОльшее знаковое.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Господа, всем спасибо за участие!

Очень помог этот ответ:
Проверяйте не в конструкторе или передавайте бОльшее знаковое. –
tocic